# Error creating AWS VPC: There was an error creating your VPC: Unable to find main route table for vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I have tried creating a VPC twice now and both times it's errored out with:

> There was an error creating your VPC: Unable to find main route table for vpc: vpc-02de8520acae014f4

I've tried using the following settings:

- Used the wizard to choose public + private
- IPv4 CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16 (no IPv6)
- VPC Name: myvpc
- Public subnet:

  - CIDR 10.0.10.0/24
  - AZ: us-east-1a
  - Name: Public Subnet A
- Private subnet:

  - CIDR 10.0.20.0/24
  - AZ: us-east-1a
  - Name: Private Subnet A
- NAT gateway:

  - Elastic IP Allocation ID: (entered an elastic ip I created)

I can't seem to find any more info beyond that error. This is a new AWS account and I've never created anything else in here. I'm on an account that has the AdministratorAccess policy.

Comment: Are you able to create any of these resources manually (outside of the wizard)?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I'm not sure, I haven't tried that yet. Is there a good resource on how to create this VPC setup with the cli? Or did you mean using the console?

Comment: You can use the console, by just creating each resource individually. Start with creating the base VPC then create the subnets as a start. Check the route tables link to ensure one is created for your VPC.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Huh, I was able to create everything. Something must be broken with the wizard. I wonder if it's a timing issue and something came up too fast?

Comment: I suspect you're right, this main route table is always created with the base VPC so I suspect there's an issue. Perhaps raise to AWS support? :)

Answer (score 2):

This error will result if you had existing subnets using the same exact private IP address. The private IP address consists of your vpc ip address + subnet ip address.
IF this is in fact the case, the subnets will not be created and the public ip address will obviously not be associated with the non created public subnet. The error message doesn't reflect the real issue though, not sure why AWS can't return a better one. In fact, if you look at the new vpc details, you will see a route table attached to it, so the error message is completely off

Comment: If this were true, why did creating everything without the wizard work?